# Does current source affect flow of current in circuit with a variable resistor?

Tags: current, resistors, current-source, ohms-law

Suppose you have a current source in series with a resistor **R** the current through the **R** resistor would be the current generated by the current source. How would the current through the circuit change if you replaced resistor **R** with resistor **Y**, where the value of resistor **Y>R**?

**Original circuit**

[image: Original circuit]

Comment: You've asked one question.  You've got answers.  You've accepted the answer.  Don't change this question.  Start a new one if you need to.

Comment: Putting an ideal current source in series with an ideal voltage source is an unresolvable error, like dividing by zero.

Comment: @pjc50: why? there are three voltage sources and one resistor in series. Assume the resistor current is 4mA, and you can calculate the resistor voltage. The voltage source voltages are of course fixed, the current source's voltage follows. No problem. Maybe you confused it with putting two current sources (with different currents in series? That is unsolvable, exactly like paralleling two (different voltage) voltage sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be exactly the same current. Only the voltage would change.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: If two components are in series, by definition, the current through them is the same. Also, by definition, an ideal current source always produces a given current. So any component (resistor of any value, diode, inductor, whatever) in series with an ideal current source, will have exactly the specified current through it.

Comment: Exactly what The Photon said. Couldn't have said it better myself. Except to plug KCL.

Answer (score 3):

The current wouldn't change if the value of R changes in this circuit.

By definition of the ideal current source, the current through it will be what's written on the schematic.  The current source will develop as much voltage as necessary for the current to be what the schematic prescribes.

An ideal current source is, well,... an idealization.  You can imagine a character like a herald with a trumpet from a fairy tail proclaiming:  "*The King said 100 mA.*"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a worked example.  Say R is a 1K resistor.

According to ohm's law, the voltage drop across the resistor is I * R, which is 4 mA * 1000 R = 4 V.

If now R is replaced with Y, and Y is 2K, then the new voltage drop across the resistor is 4 mA * 2000 R = 8 V.

So since the current by definition is constant,  The voltage changes with the resistance in a linear fashion.